# Twin cylinder engine opposed cylinders

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, vibration

Hoping this is the best area to ask this, mostly in the DIY and hobby world I've seen 2 engines coupled together to make a twin engine some so this for the zen of doing, but others do it to align the pistons I've noticed particularly in RC aircraft rather than buy a twin engine where the pistons operate at exactly the same time and I supposed matched this  Introduces a reciprocating vibration that causes issues.

I've been hearing if you take 2 two stroke engines and couple them together with 1 at TDC and the other at BDC they cancel each other out and a guy on YouTube showed a video of one with a glass of water next to it barely moving.

What is the name for such an arrangement? Is there any disadvantage of doing this? Links to more information? I shall search for YouTube video as described above.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the arrangement used for Volkswagen (air-cooled) engines was known as *horizontally-opposed* when I worked on them. The cylinders were slightly offset from each other and each cylinder had its own crankshaft journal, so not *exactly* opposed, but perhaps along the lines of what you were looking for.

I've also heard them called *pancake* engines, which might turn up some other search results.

On blacksmith37's excellent comment, here's what the BMW motorcycle version looks like inside (these days at least).

[image]

For some reason I never discovered, these were sometimes called "boxer" engines, which might provide another fruitful search term.

Comment: BMW motorcycles have used horizontal twins forever , although 4 cycle.  And they were copied by the Russian Ural.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course! How could I forget! Many a happy mile putted around by one of those! :)